# Need to increment patch tag version based on releaseVersion in groovy pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to increment patch version based off releaseVersion in groovy pipeline code

if file == build-manifest/pp5/manifest.json

Read releaseVersion from manifest (ex. 1.2)
Read all tags in current repo
Increment patch version based off releaseVersion.
For example all tags show a latest version of 1.2.5. Read releaseVersion and if 1.2, increment patch version to 1.2.6.
– or –
If repo has 1.2.5 and releaseVersion is 1.3, add tag 1.3.0

I have coded below to extract patch tag version and release version but how can we increment it in groovy?

````
  agent {
    node {
      label 'allinone'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Get git tags') {
      steps {
        checkout([
          $class: 'GitSCM',
          branches: [[name: "*/master"]],
          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
          extensions: [[
            $class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
            relativeTargetDir: "${WORKSPACE}"
          ]],
          submoduleCfg: [],
          userRemoteConfigs: [[
            credentialsId: 'bitbucket-jenkins',
            url: "${repo}"
          ]]
        ])
      }
    }

    stage('Get upstream branches') {
      steps {
        script {
          dir("${WORKSPACE}") {
            sh """
              pwd
              ls
              git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format '%(tag)' refs/tags
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Verifying manifest file'){
      steps {
          sh """
              if [ -f manifest.json ]; then echo "File Exist"; fi
              export releaseVersion=\$(jq -c .app.releaseVersion manifest.json | sed 's/\"/\\\\\"/g')              

            """
      }  
    }
  }
}```
````